# Dynamic Model Sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So admittedly I am a complete newbie to MVC and I am having a great deal of difficulty on this.

I have my DB table being instantiated by a IEntryRepository to the Entity Framework in the Entry Controller. I can pull the data, my paging helper appears to be functioning. I can even filter the results. But I'm having a terrible time figuring out how to sort the columns.

From the controller:

```
   public ViewResult Entries(string Specialty, string sortOrder, string CurrentSort, int page = 1)
    {
        //ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

        //sortOrder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "TimeStamp" : sortOrder;

        //for testing
        sortOrder = "Case";

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Case":
                sortOrder = "p.Case";
                break;

            case "Timestamp":
                sortOrder = "p.TimeStamp";
                break;

            case "Origin":
                sortOrder = "Origin";
                break;

            case "AssignedTo":
                sortOrder = "AssignedTo";
                break;

            case "AssignedBy":
                sortOrder = "AssignedBy";
                break;
        }

        EntryListViewModel model = new EntryListViewModel
        {
            Entry = repository.Entries.AsQueryable()
            .Where(p => Specialty == null || p.Sub == Specialty)
            .OrderBy(p => sortOrder)
            .Skip((page - 1) * pagesize)
            .Take(pagesize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = pagesize,
                TotalItems = Specialty == null ?
                repository.Entries.Count() :
                repository.Entries.Where(p => p.Sub == Specialty).Count()
            },

            CurrentCategory = Specialty
        };


        return View(model);
    }
```

From the View:

```
@model ProjectSquid.WebUI.Models.EntryListViewModel


<table class="entries">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.ActionLink("Case Number", "Entries", "Entry", new {Specialty = Model.CurrentCategory, sortOrder = "Case", CurrentSort = ViewBag.CurrentSort}) </th>
            <th>Time Stamp </th>
            <th>Origin </th>
            <th>Assigned To </th>
            <th>Assigned By </th>
            <th>Customer Name </th>
            <th>Customer Phone </th>
            <th>Comments </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="entry">
        @foreach (var p in Model.Entry)
        {
            <tr>
                <td title="@p.Case">@p.Case</td>
                <td title="@p.TimeStamp">@p.TimeStamp</td>
                <td title="@p.Origin">@p.Origin</td>
                <td title="@p.AssignedTo">@p.AssignedTo</td>
                <td title="@p.AssignedBy">@p.AssignedBy</td>
                <td title="@p.CustomerName">@p.CustomerName</td>
                <td title="@p.CustomerPhone">@p.CustomerPhone</td>
                <td title="@p.Comments">@p.Comments</td>
                @if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){<td>Delete</td>}
            </tr>}
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="pager">
        @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("Entries",
        new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory }))
</div>
```

I know there are a bunch of errors in this but my main question is why does the .OrderBy not accept anything I pass to it? Is this an improper way of using Lambda? How else can it be done?

I've found quite a few tutorials but none of them seem to deal with sorting an Entity Framework Model.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

**EDIT (Fixed):**

Controller:

```
    public ViewResult Entries(string Specialty, string sortOrder, int page = 1)
    {
        //ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

        //sortOrder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "TimeStamp" : sortOrder;

        var Query = repository.Entries
            .Where(p => Specialty == null || p.Sub == Specialty);

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            default:
                Query = Query.OrderByDescending(p => p.TimeStamp);
                break;

            case "Case":
                Query = Query.OrderBy(p => p.Case);
                break;

            case "Timestamp":
                Query = Query.OrderBy(p => p.TimeStamp);
                break;

            case "Origin":
                Query = Query.OrderBy(p => p.Origin);
                break;

            case "AssignedTo":
                Query = Query.OrderBy(p => p.AssignedTo);
                break;

            case "AssignedBy":
                Query = Query.OrderBy(p => p.AssignedBy);
                break;
        }

        EntryListViewModel model = new EntryListViewModel
        {
            Entry = Query
            //.Where(p => Specialty == null || p.Sub == Specialty)
            //.OrderBy(p => sortOrder)
            .Skip((page - 1) * pagesize)
            .Take(pagesize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = pagesize,
                TotalItems = Specialty == null ?
                    Query.Count() :
                    Query.Where(p => p.Sub == Specialty).Count()
            },
            _SortOrder = sortOrder,
            _CurrentCategory = Specialty
        };


        return View(model);
    }
```

I also had to create an HTML Helper class to do the sorting while maintaining page number. Still working but now I'm actually making progress, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the `OrderBy` function work is it expects a lambda expression that returns a property of the object, and you're trying to throw in a string. One way to do what you want is to re-structure your code like this: (this is untested but should give you the idea):

```
 var query = repository.Entries
                       .Where(p => Specialty == null || p.Sub == Specialty);

 switch (sortOrder)
 {
    case "Case":
        query = query.OrderBy(p => p.Case);
        break;

    case "Timestamp":
        query = query.OrderBy(p => p.TimeStamp);
        break;

    case "Origin":
        query = query.OrderBy(p => p.Origin);
        break;
 **SNIP**

var Entry = query.Skip((page - 1) * pagesize)
                  .Take(pagesize)
                  .ToList() //You probably need this here
```

Don't worry if you think this query is inefficient, thanks to deferred execution, the database won't actually be queries until you try to materialize the result with `ToList()`